# runtime exception in converting uiswitch value to string

Tags: xcode

I am getting a runtime exception here,  i think it's with converting switch boolean value to string

```
[care_checkin_data setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",switch.on] forKey:@"ispresentable"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifier %@ is for an Objective-C object, instead switch.on returns a BOOL. 
 Maybe you need to set your object as an NSNumber:

```
[care_checkin_data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:switch.on] forKey:@"ispresentable"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how the value should be stored in the `care_checkin_data` dictionary?  If you want `true` or `false` then this will do it:

```
[care_checkin_data setObject:(switch.on ? @"true" : @"false")
                      forKey:@"ispresentable"];
```